# Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('application/gzip') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server, helmet.js

I am trying to setup helmet security on my react application production server. But whenever I try hitting the URL. I get an error saying `Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/static/js/app.378bd8b8eee930fb268c.js' because its MIME type ('application/gzip') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

[image]

For compression build I am using `compression-webpack-plugin`.

The compression build is working perfectly fine when I remove the `helmet`. 
Helmet Plugin Setting:

```
{"xssFilter": {"setOnOldIE": true}}
```

Comment: Why are you making XSS verification? I don't get the point there. What are you trying to do? What is ```http://localhost:3000/static/js/app.378bd8b8eee930fb268c.js``` supposed to respond?

Comment: @AirOne I am using it to protect my application from X-XSS-Protection

Comment: As said on helmet doc, XSS Filter doesn't do much. I recommend you to not use helmet but manually set ```X-XSS Protection``` header to ```1; mode=block``` instead.

Comment: @AirOne Your idea worked (Y). Thank You

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: `/static/js/app.378bd8b8eee930fb268c.js` is being sent with a `Content-Type` of `application/gzip` but it should be `application/javascript`.

---

Author of Helmet here. This is happening because of the `X-Content-Type-Options` header, which Helmet automatically sets to `nosniff`. This tells browsers not to infer the type of the file, and to trust the `Content-Type` that the server sets.

As you can see in your screenshot, `/static/js/app.378bd8b8eee930fb268c.js` has a `Content-Type` of `application/gzip`. The browser refuses to interpret it as JavaScript because its `Content-Type` isn't `application/javascript`—that's the `X-Content-Type-Options` header in action.

You can fix your problem by fixing that—get your JavaScript files' `Content-Type`s to be `application/javascript`, not `application/gzip`.

Comment: Now I am getting:  `Refused to execute script from ‘http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendor.99d99f68deb71905f4ce.js’ because its MIME type (‘application/json’) is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: Apologies, I had a typo—it should be `application/javascript`, not `application/json`.